# passing class objects as parameters for Invoke Method using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

What is the syntax for sending a class object as a parameter using the `Invoke` method?

The `Invoke` method call is causing an error:

> "Object of type 'MSM_ns.MyParameterClass' cannot be converted to type 'MSM_ns.MyParameterClass'"

Parameters of basic data types work fine, but complex data types cause errors.

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };

MyParameterClass myParams = new MyParametersClass("ABC", 123, 3.14159);

// attach to the dll
MethodInfo dllMethodInfo = Invoke.LoadDLL("MSM.dll", "MSM_ns", "MSMClass", "MSMMethod1");

// attach the parameters
object[] parameters = new object[2];
parameters[0] = data; 
parameters[1] = myParams;

// call the DLL
bool result = (bool)dllMethodInfo.Invoke(null, parameters);

--------

public static bool MSMMethod1(ref byte[] dataToVerify, MyParameterClass myParams)
{
   . . .
}
```

Comment: The parameter (almost definitely) shouldn't be `ref`

Comment: What's `Invoke.LoadDLL`?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the same assembly twice, with two identical but incompatible types.

You need to only load the assembly once.

Comment: //MethodInfo dllMethodInfo = Invoke.LoadDLL("MSM.dll", "MSM_ns", "MSMClass", "MSMMethod1");
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile("MSM.dll");
Type classObj = dll.GetType("MSM_ns" + "." + "MSMClass");
MethodInfo dllMethodInfo = classObj.GetMethod("MSMMethod1");

Comment: //MethodInfo dllMethodInfo = Invoke.LoadDLL("MSM.dll", "MSM_ns", "MSMClass", "MSMMethod1");

Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile("MSM.dll");

Type classObj = dll.GetType("MSM_ns" + "." + "MSMClass");

MethodInfo dllMethodInfo = classObj.GetMethod("MSMMethod1");